# Can you die from an Unknown Location?

Tags: slay-the-spire

I encountered an Unknown Location (aka a ? room) with an option to upgrade 2 cards but would make me lose 16 HP. I encountered this room while I only had 1 hp. If I had taken the upgrade, would the room have killed me? Or is there a safety net to prevent me from dying in one of these rooms?

[image: Offer to upgrade card]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will definitely die in situations like these. Unless you have something like the lizard tail relic (when you would die, heal to 50%) or a fairy potion (When you take fatal damage, heal to 30%.) to prevent death/give you more health your run will end when your health reaches 0.

I also believe that your potions are still interactable at this screen meaning that if you had a health potion to bring you above the kill mark, you can use it and take the upgrade buff.